# ASP.NET Browser Compatibility (Chrome)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, browser

ASP.NET application works perfectly in Internet browser but in chrome it hangs on a validate page when it suppose to submit data and move to another page , it sounds like ASP.NET AJAX broken or browser compatibility !

ASP.NET page submit's hangs up IN chrome however works in internet explorer, no error logs either , except time out ?

in network tab its running this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            <!--
            if(document.getElementById)
            { // IE 5 and up, NS 6 and up
                var upLevel = true;
            }

            else if(document.layers)
            { // Netscape 4
                var ns4 = true;
            }
```

Comment: You need to add some code to make your question answerable.

Comment: I highly doubt it'll be ASP.Net that has the cross-browser issues.

Comment: This is why I always create web-pages to work in Chrome/FireFox, then break them to work in IE.

Comment: @Ryan didn;t get ya, and can anyone tell me what this script is doing please

Comment: I highly suggest using a tried-and-tested library like jQuery() to do the main work of cross-browser stuff.

Comment: @ Moo-Juice can you explain the solution please

Comment: @user1090104, well it's not a specific solution to your problem (hence I put it as a comment rather than an answer).  From the jQuery website:- "jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chrome developer tools to find out what's going on. There is a network tab that will show you the activity going on in Chrome, and why it's hanging up.

I also doubt this is an asp.net issue, it sounds more like something is wrong with the application.

**Update**

Thanks for posting code. Now, you can use Chrome developer tools to set a breakpoint. Do that, execute the problematic action, then step through the script to find out exactly where it is hanging up. I doubt it's on the simple if/else statement you posted, there has to be more script that comes after that.

Answer (score 1):

it would be best to post the code where it hangs up, insert a breakpoint and see where it happens.  Also in chrome you can do "Inspect Element" and it might give you details to whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused on how it's not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/wb3dz/

There needs to be more to your mark-up than just that.

Is it "hanging" or just not displaying anything? There is a substantial difference between the two.

Let's step back from this issue and look at the script you posted. Why are you determining the browser version?

Inside those if's you have :

```
var upLevel = true;
var ns4 = true;
```

however, those variables are declared within a specific scope and are un-usable outside of it. That being said, that if.else statement you have there is moot and can be removed.
If you remove that logic block, will your website load?